# PanGesture is calling Pangesture updated event only one time in UWP Xamarin Forms. That is why dragging is not performing

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, uipangesturerecognizer

I have added Pan Gesture on Image using code behind, then in pan gesture updated method i have called all cases of it.

Its going in running case at once and set native view(Image) coordinate  relative to Parent view(Window). Then it stops and not perform any call to pan gesture updated method.Below is the code.

```
/*Creation of image*/
void CreateImage() {
    var panGestureRecognizer = new PanGestureRecognizer();
    panGestureRecognizer.PanUpdated += PanGestureRecognizer_PanUpdated;
    Image image = new Image()
    {
        HeightRequest = 40,
        WidthRequest = 40,
        Margin = new Thickness( 10, 10, 10, 0 ),
        Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit,
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
        Source = ImageSource.FromUri( new Uri( $"{codebookJSONModel.Violation.IconPath}" ) ),
    };
    image.GestureRecognizers.Add( panGestureRecognizer );
}

/*PanGesture Updated Event*/

private async void PanGestureRecognizer_PanUpdated( object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e ) {
    Console.WriteLine( "PanGestureRecognizer_PanUpdated" );
    var layout = (Image)sender;
    switch ( e.StatusType ) {
    case GestureStatus.Started:
        Console.WriteLine( "PanGestureRecognizer_Started" );
        inspectionViewModel.totalX = 0;
        inspectionViewModel.totalY = 0;
        break;

    case GestureStatus.Running:
        // Translate and ensure we don't pan beyond the wrapped user interface element bounds.
        Debug.WriteLine( "PanGestureRecognizer_Running" );
        var screenCoordinates = DependencyService.Get<ICommonDependent>().GetViewPositionInSuperView( layout, this.Content );
        inspectionViewModel.totalX = e.TotalX;
        inspectionViewModel.totalY = e.TotalY;


        Debug.WriteLine( "e.TotalX: " + e.TotalX + "e.TotalY: " + e.TotalY );
        double superViewX = screenCoordinates.x + inspectionViewModel.totalX;
        double superViewY = screenCoordinates.y + inspectionViewModel.totalY - layout.Height / 2;
        uxViolationMarkerImgView.IsVisible = true;

        Debug.WriteLine( $"x = {superViewX}, y = {superViewY}" );
        DisplayOnGoingMarkerAsView( superViewX, superViewY );
        break;

    case GestureStatus.Completed:
        // Store the translation applied during the pan
        Debug.WriteLine( "PanGestureRecognizer_Completed" );
        var lastScreenCoordinates = DependencyService.Get<ICommonDependent>().GetViewPositionInSuperView( layout, uxMapView );

        double mapViewX = lastScreenCoordinates.x + inspectionViewModel.totalX + layout.Width / 2;
        double mapViewY = lastScreenCoordinates.y + inspectionViewModel.totalY + layout.Height / 2;
        Debug.WriteLine( $"x = {mapViewX}, y = {mapViewY}" );

        uxViolationMarkerImgView.IsVisible = false;
        break;
    case GestureStatus.Canceled:
        Debug.WriteLine( "PanGestureRecognizer_Canceled" );
        uxViolationMarkerImgView.IsVisible = false;
        break;
    }
}

/*GetViewPositionInSuperView method to get child element position inside window*/

public ( double x, double y ) GetViewPositionInSuperView( Xamarin.Forms.View layout, Xamarin.Forms.View superview = null ) {
    var nativeView = Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.Platform.GetRenderer( layout ).ContainerElement;
    FrameworkElement relativePositionView;
    if ( superview != null ) {
        relativePositionView = Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.Platform.GetRenderer( superview ).ContainerElement;
    } else {
        relativePositionView = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
    }

    var element_Visual_Relative = nativeView.TransformToVisual( relativePositionView );
    ///element_Visual_Relative.TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));

    Rect rectangle = element_Visual_Relative.TransformBounds( new Rect( new Point( nativeView.Margin.Left, nativeView.Margin.Top ), nativeView.RenderSize ) );

    Console.WriteLine( $"NativeX: {rectangle.X} NativeY: {rectangle.Y}" );
    return ( rectangle.X, rectangle.Y );
}
```

Comment: Does it just have the issue in uwp , does it only fire once on other platforms?

Comment: Its just occuring for Uwp Xamarin.forms, on other platform like ios its working fine.